# C# Paste Clipboard content into Excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, clipboard, worksheet-function

As the title says, I try to actually paste what is in my Clipboard into an Excel.

I've following code:

```
Clipboard.SetText(html);
sheet.Range("A1").Value = Clipboard.GetText();
```

Actually, the variable html contains a html code file, when I do it like that, I actually paste only the html content into the Range, but, if I open Excel and do by hand, Paste Special... I can paste the html code, but it transforms the code into a real table instead of a html code and this is the real result that I want, without doing it by hand.

[Excel.Range.Copy() paste with Clipboard.GetText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529483/excel-range-copy-paste-with-clipboard-gettext)

Another way was:

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in workbook.Sheets)
{
    foreach (Excel.Shape shape in sheet.Shapes)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(html);

        //doesn't work:                              
        sheet.Range("A1").Value = sheet.PasteSpecial(Clipboard.GetText()); 

        sheet.PasteSpecial(Clipboard.GetText()); //throws error
    }
}
```

But this way doesn't work too. I can do it with an html -> image and paste the image, but real values should be accessible and not a picture.

Hope someone can clarify how to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147152/excel-paste-special-and-add-operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to use `SetData` instead of `SetText`:

```
 Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Html, html);
```

to copy the string into the clipboard and tag it as HTML (if this does not work in your case, `SetText`may be ok).

The call to `PasteSpecial` for the cell range where you want the insert to happen, taking regard to your comments:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(
         Excel.Enums.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll,
         Excel.Enums.Xl‌​PasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,
         false, false);
```

Note that assigning a cell a new value by using the `Value` property **never** copies any formats etc.

Comment: I was thinking about that way, but it still throws me an exception, I'm using NetOffice instead of Microsoft.Office libraries that's why, because I can just do a .PasteSpecial without parameters. I'll wait a reply from admin there to ask if it might be an assembly issue or a wrong implementation. It seems to compile with : sheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(Excel.Enums.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll,Excel.Enums.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd,false, false);  But still get some exception error.

Comment: I did it with xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd , because I already have existing values from an template ... And want to do calculations from previous existing values, if I leave it with xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, old values are kept, but still get an exception error. RTFM was read, since you even gave me the right Operation.

Comment: Just for copying it works with

Clipboard.SetText(html);
sheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial();

He doesn't like the Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Htlm, html);

Comment: @mike27015: ok, changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
    xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(Missing.Value, false, false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

//below is the complete code

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

            Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlApp.Visible = true;
            xlApp.UserControl = true;
            xlApp.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
           // xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excel_filename);
            xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1].Activate();
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(Missing.Value, false, false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(save_file_name);
            Console.WriteLine("saved file name" + save_file_name);
            xlWorkBook.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the copied cells from the Clipboard by using

```
    Clipboard.GetData("XML Spreadsheet");
```

Then, after I did some copy-pasting through my code, I put it back with

```
    Clipboard.SetData("XML Spreadsheet", originalObject);
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

my simple C# Copy & Paste ( from Input/Sheet[1] to Output/Sheet[1] )

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

// prepare Input
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileNameIn);
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;      //I copy everything
// prepare Output
        Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
        oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
        Excel.Workbook mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(fileNameOut, 0, false, 5,
                                "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
                                "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        Excel.Worksheet mWSheet1 = mWorkBook.Sheets[1];
// make Copy&Paste in PC memory
        xlRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
        Excel.Range targetRange = mWSheet1.Cells[11, 1];   //initial cell for Paste
        mWSheet1.Paste(targetRange);
// save Output
        mWorkBook.SaveAs(fileNameOut, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, 
                                Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                                Missing.Value, Missing.Value,  
                                Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                                Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                                Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
// clean the waste !
        mWorkBook.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        mWSheet1 = null; mWorkBook = null; oXL.Quit();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange); Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);
        xlWorkbook.Close(); Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
        xlApp.Quit(); Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is for dump html string into the excel

```html
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void ExcelExport()
{
    var excel = new Application { Visible = true };
    excel.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
    Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
    Worksheet sheet = workbook.Sheets[1];
    sheet.Activate();

    string s = "<html><body><table>";

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        s += "<tr>";

        for (int f = 1; f <= 100; f++)
        {
            s += "<td>" + i.ToString() + "," + f.ToString() + "</td>";
        }

        s += "</tr>";
    }

    s += "</table></body></html>";

    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(s);

    sheet.Range["A1"].Select();
    sheet.PasteSpecial(Type.Missing, false, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    sheet.Range["A1"].Select();
}
```